# Convergence to a constant in probability but not almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Please give a example that a sequence of random variables that converge to a
constant $c$ in probability but fail to converge to $c$ with probability $1$.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Has been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368201/a-sequence-of-random-variables-that-converge-to-a-constant-c-in-probability-but) but cannot vote to close since it does not have an answers.

Answer (score 4):

My apologies, I had posted an answer earlier which was wrong. So here is the correct one:

Define $\Omega = [0,1]$. Let $A_1=[0,\frac{1}{2}],A_2= [\frac{1}{2},1],A_3=[0,\frac{1}{4}], A_4=[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]... $

In general $$ A_{2^n + k - 1} = [\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}] \quad k \in \{1,..2^n\}$$

It is of note that $P(A_k) \geq P(A_{k+1})$. In fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_k) = 0$.

Define $X_k = 1_{A_k}$. Now $X_k \to 0 \quad i.p$ because $\forall \epsilon > 0$
$$P(X_m > \epsilon) = P(X_m = 1) = P(A_m)$$

Take limits to conclude that $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

Now for the a.s debunking. $X_n \to 0$ a.s is equivalent to showing $\forall \epsilon > 0$
$$ P(\cap_{k\geq 1}\cup_{n \geq k}\{X_n \geq \epsilon\}) = 0$$
$$ \iff P(\cap_{k\geq 1}\cup_{n \geq k}A_n) = 0$$

Now $\cup_{n \geq m}A_n = \Omega$ because if you pick a m, find a j s.t $m < 2^j$ and then
$$\cup_{l=1}^{2^j-1}A_{2^j + l} = \Omega \subseteq \cup_{n \geq m}A_n$$ Thus
$$P(\cap_{k\geq 1}\cup_{n \geq k}A_n) = 1 $$

Thus $X_n$ does not converge to 0 a.s.

Comment: can you help clarify the last step? Why is the union of the intervals from $2^j$ to $2^j+2^{j+1}$ equal to the entire $[0,1]$ interval?